# Can I specify labels on sent mail in GMail?

Tags: gmail, gmail-labels

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Label outgoing emails in Gmail when composing the mail](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/2228/label-outgoing-emails-in-gmail-when-composing-the-mail)

I use GMail's labels extensively, and would often like to specify labels on email I'm sending - specifically I have a **waiting** label for stuff I need to follow up with if I don't get a reply. But there are plenty of other labels I'd like to attach to outgoing email sometimes.

Is there a way to do this without having to go to the Sent Mail folder after I've sent the email?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

One method is to CC the message to yourself -- or even better, to yourname+waiting@gmail.com -- and have a filter on your e-mail address which then applies the Waiting label.

Answer (score 2):

Originally posted to the [possible duplicate](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/2228/label-outgoing-emails-in-gmail-when-composing-the-mail/4766#4766) (thanks for the pointer, rchern):

> You can apply labels to drafts, and they seem to stick after the message is sent. It's an extra step, but since I often write messages and come back to them later to polish and send it works for me.

Comment: Rather than copying and pasting answers between duplicate questions, this question should be closed as a duplicate that points back to the original question.

Comment: How would one go about doing so? I don't think I have the reputation score necessary to accomplish that. But then, this question appears to have an accepted answer that differs from the top-scoring answer on the other one... Maybe that's a good reason to keep it around, for the perspective.

Answer (score 2):

Best way I've found to do this is to:

- Compose mails in a new window (shortcut is 'C' (Shift+c) or you can just click the icon in the top right).
- In the original window, go to your drafts folder and label the message as you wish.
- Continue composing your message and send it - the label will remain.

(copied from [the question for which this is a duplicate](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/2228/label-outgoing-emails-in-gmail-when-composing-the-mail))

Answer (score 1):

Create a filter with "me" in the "From" field and tell it to apply the "waiting" label (or any other label you want). Of course, you can specify other criteria for the filter if you don't want the label to apply to all outgoing mail.