# Can I label a message in Gmail before I send it?

Tags: gmail, gmail-labels

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Label outgoing emails in Gmail when composing the mail](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/2228/label-outgoing-emails-in-gmail-when-composing-the-mail)

Some of the messages I send in Gmail I need to label.  Right now I'm having to go into the Sent Items and select them and apply the label.  It would be nice if there was some way to label them before I've sent the message (while I'm composing it).

Any ideas?