# Starred sent messages in Gmail

Tags: gmail

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Label outgoing emails in Gmail when composing the mail](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/2228/label-outgoing-emails-in-gmail-when-composing-the-mail)

I star incoming messages in Gmail to keep track of which ones need replies.

I'd like to be able to do the same thing with sent messages. As I'm sending them, star or tag them so that I'll be able to view a list of them later, to make sure I got replies.

Is there a way to do this, or in general deal with sent messages better within Gmail, so that the conversation doesn't just disappear if the other person doesn't reply?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can add a label and/or star the message while you are composing:

[image: Screenshot of GMail send message]

[See this on unofficial gmailblog on blogspot](http://gmailblog.blogspot.fr/2012/03/star-and-label-messages-before-you-send.html)

Comment: That's interesting - but it doesn't seem to make them show up in my starred-first inbox.  But if I view all starred messages, they show up!  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Messages you send are shown in your :All Mail View and/or Sent View

After you send the email, you can either go to the Sent Items (Keyboard shourcut: G + T) or the the All Mail (Keyboard shortbut: G + A) And Star the message.

Also, if you have the keyboard shortcut on - It's as simple as pressing the 'S' letter.