# Hotkeys for GMail's "New Compose"

Tags: gmail, keyboard-shortcuts

Does GMail's "New Compose" support hotkeys?

With the old compose I could label mails I am writing with easily with the hotkey `l`. See [Label outgoing emails in Gmail when composing the mail](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/2228/label-outgoing-emails-in-gmail-when-composing-the-mail?rq=1)

But with the "New Compose" I always have to use the mouse to label, because the hotkeys seem not to work anymore. Is there a better way to label?

Comment: Looking at [their support article](https://support.google.com/mail/answer/6594?hl=en), looks like such a keyboard shortcut does not exist.

Comment: How did this work with the _old_ compose? The `l` hotkey does not work for me in the _old_ compose. (I have hotkeys enabled.)

Comment: @Hydra: That is the support article for the "old" compose and includes the `l` keyboard shortcut?

Comment: @w3d Its the old composing experience (if the new compose is the popup style of composing emails)

Comment: I click Tab several times until focus on Attach button, then click Enter. You can check also other hotkeys, just press Shift+? when focus on Send button for example. wbw

Comment: How does this answer the question?

Answer (score 2):

GMail's "New Compose" doesn't support hotkeys since it has to allow for text entry.

There are however ways to use the keyboard to access the submenu as ashtu mentioned.

If you would like to label the message first before doing anything else, you can push shift tab to immediately jump to the drop down menu, then push space or arrow key up/down to expand the menu, then arrow up/down to label submenu, and then arrow right to expand to the label context menu.

If you were to label the message after writing the email, then it's a lot more cumbersome to navigate to that submenu using tabs.

In either case, it would likely be much more efficient to have a script to automate the tab presses.

In my opinion, a more efficient way to label would be to send the messages first, then navigate to the sent mail folder, and label the messages (in bulk) from there.

Answer (score 0):

Try this,
[image]
Then, 
[image]
Scroll down, Then SAVE
[image]

Using TAB to move until (3 dot) then ENTER ---> (up down keyboard) select "Label"--> click right arrow on keyboard--> (up down keyboard) select your label---> enter

[image]